# html5 audio player autoplay is not working on squarespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using html5 audio player in squarespace. But it did not start playing auto. I have add autoplay tag but not work.

I am looking for some javaescript function to trigger play button on page load.

How to create some js function?

```
<audio controls loop autoplay>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div id="music"></div>
```

Now Inside script :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#music').innerHTML = '<audio controls loop autoplay> <source src = "horse.mp3" type = "audio/mpeg"></audio>'

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You facing [browser limitation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) to prevent noisy tab who automatically playing sound.

If you open this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRajra) and check console output. You will find all detail about why is not allowed.

Chrome and modern browser will wait for first user interaction before to start any media.

So you can create fullscreen overlay and, on click on it, start your audio.

```js
(function(){  
  var audio2 = document.querySelector('.muted');

 

// WHen you click on overlay  
  document.querySelector('.activate').addEventListener('click',function(){
    audio2.muted = false; // Unmute
    audio2.play(); // Play 
    document.querySelector('.activate').style.display = 'none'; //hide overlay
  },true);
})();
```

```css
.fullscreen {
  position : fixed;
  left : 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<p>Second player : will start as muted </p>
<audio class='muted' controls loop autoplay muted src="http://marc.ucla.edu/mpeg/01_Breathing_Meditation.mp3"></audio>

<div class="fullscreen activate">
  
</div>
```

Then you can click anywhere on your page to start audio.